# NSNotification not working

Tags: ios, xcode

I have have been trying to get `NSNotification` to work. For a test, I wanted a button that loads a new viewController using storyBoards. When you click the button it should trigger a notification for the appObserver to pick up in the second ViewController (I've named Page2). In Page2 the the `NSNotificationCenter` should launch a method (myMethod:) and print out a simple `NSLog`.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work as myMethod does not get called. what am I doing wrong ???

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)goToPage2Button:(id)sender {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"test" object:nil];

}

#import "Page2.h"

@interface Page2 ()

@end


@implementation Page2

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethod:) name:@"test" object:nil];


    }
    return self;
}

-(void)myMethod:(NSNotification *)notification{


    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"test"])
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be because your page2 view controller does not exist when the notification is fired.

The second view controller registers for observation when it wakes from it's nib, but if it hasn't been created, then it hasn't registered for the notification that your first view controller is sending.

What you should be doing is using segues to load view controllers based on actions.

Comment: @Abizem - Thanks for putting me in the right direction. Ive just learnt how to pass data using segues and it works brilliantly.

Answer (score 4):

When you use storyboards, `initWithNibName` is generally not called. It uses `initWithCoder`. Are you sure you're getting to that line of code that adds your observer?

If you ever get behavior that looks like some line of code isn't getting called, it's always good to put a breakpoint there or a `NSLog` and confirm that it does.

Comment: Good catch, `awakeFromNib` is also a viable method to put customisation in.

Comment: @Rob - thanks Rob - you're right. The observer was not getting called at all in the initWithNibName. For now, I have changed my app by using Aabizems suggestion about Segues.

Comment: Yeah, if using storyboards, `prepareForSegue` is the best way to pass data from a segue's `sourceController` to its `destinationController`. If you want to pass stuff from the destination controller back to the source controller, using a `delegate` or reference the destination's `presentingViewController` makes sense. `UINotificationCenter` is perfect, though, when sharing data possibly with multiple view controllers (e.g. you have some asynchronous background job, retrieving data from a remote server, and you want to let any view controllers currently running that the download is complete).